# Is it possible to have a multi select list box in Google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to have a multi select list box on a google sheet using an app script?

I found a way that can be partially achieved by having a [multi dropdown](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/128693153/multiple-selection-in-drop-down-menu?hl=en) but a user need to select & wait a few seconds before selecting other one. There is also an issue where you might end up selecting multiple times same name; having a checkbox would be more efficient.

Below google sheet, POC1 is the column where I would like to have list box which would allow to select multiple names among the list of names & show in the same cell, split by delimiter.

[image: Google Sheet]

Would be great to have something like below in POC1 column cells, but this is using [excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1358450/how-do-i-add-checkboxes-inside-a-dropdown-in-excel-or-google-sheets), would like to know how can be replicated on Google Sheet as we use Gsuite at work.

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: I would use a dialog or sidebar

Comment: @Cooper Can you please ellaborate?

Comment: The built-in data validation doesn't support that; Google Sheets / Apps Script haven't anything equivalent to the Excel / VBA interactive elements. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Using App Script:

Here's a way to do it using apps script and custom menu

**1.)** Go to **Extensions -> Apps Script**. Rename the **Code.gs** to **SERVER.gs**. Now copy and paste the codes from below to replace everything inside

```
/**
 * Changes the variable validation if needed
 */

var validation = {
    sheet: 'VALIDATION',
    range: 'A2:A'
}

/**
 * Creates a menu entry in the Google Docs UI when the document is opened.
 *
 * @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onOpen trigger. To
 *     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
 *     running in, inspect e.authMode.
 */
function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Sidebar')
        .addItem('Show Sidebar', 'showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
        showSidebar();
}


/**
 * Opens a sidebar in the document containing the add-on's user interface.
 */

function showSidebar() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .showSidebar(HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('SIDEBAR')
            .evaluate()
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
            .setTitle('Multiple selector'));
}

function getOptions() {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(validation.sheet).getRange(validation.range).getDisplayValues()
        .filter(String)
        .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a.concat(b)
        })
}

function process(arr) {
    arr.length > 0 ? SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().clearContent().setValue(arr.join(", ")) :
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('No options selected')
}
```

**2.)** Create a new file in the script editor by clicking the Plus(+) sign then click HTML. Name this SIDEBAR.html.

[image]

**3.)** Replace the content by the codes from below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    .container,
    .buttons {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 13px;
    }
</style>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <p>
            <button class="action" id="action">Fill active cell</button>
            <button id="btn">Rebuild options</button>
        </p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            createList();
            var selected = [];
            $('.ui.checkbox').checkbox();
            $("#action").click(function() {
                $("input:checkbox[name=sel]:checked").each(function() {
                    selected.push($(this).val());
                    $(this).prop( "checked", false ); 
                });
                google.script.run.process(selected)
                selected.length = 0;
            });
            $("#btn").click(function() {
                createList();
            });
        });

        function options(arr) {
            $(".container").empty();
            $(arr).each(function(i, el) {
                $(".container").append('<div class="field"><div class="ui checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="sel" value="' + el + '"><label>' + el + '</label></div></div>')
            });
        }

        function createList() {
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(options).getOptions()
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**4.)** Refresh your spreadsheet you should now have the custom menu **Sidebar**. [image]

**5.)** Add a sheet named "Validation" here is where you will put the options available to select. Start from the row 2.

[image]

**6.)** Click Sidebar > **Show Sidebar**. A side bar should open  on the right with the list of options that you have added in the validation sheet.

[image]

**7.)**  Select the cell where you want to input the selected options. You can now select multiple items from the options.
[image]

**References:**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gsnzgvvx2y8 , option 1
- [Multiple items from dropdown](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/1993362?hl=en)
- Here is a sample sheet, and where you can get the apps script code: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cam1LNJgvWVDx_gmEVmPzuTYaITmsQWhZ7tlcHwAmCY/copy

Comment: This script looks very promising however Google refuses to authorise the script, when I grant it permission in a pop-up Google blocks the access, as follows: `This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.`

Comment: What is that initial Semantic library you're loading in (https://cdn.rawgit.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI/6e6d051d47b598ebab05857545f242caf2b4b48c/dist/semantic.min.js)?

Comment: @lampShadesDrifter It's a well-known web UI development library.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in a named zone 'items'

```
var items = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('items').getValues().flat()
```

By script as follows

```
function inputMultipleCheckBoxesSidebar() {
  var page = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><form><table>`
  items.forEach(c => page += `<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="xxx" value="${c}"></td><td>${c}</td></tr>`)
  page += `</table></form><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="form_data()" >
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="document.forms[0].reset()" />
  <script>
      function form_data(){
        var checkedValues = []; 
        var inputElements = document.getElementsByName('xxx');
        for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
          if(inputElements[i].checked){
            checkedValues.push(inputElements[i].value);
          }
        }
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getCheckedValues(checkedValues);
      };
</script></body></html>`
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(page).setTitle("Your title ...")
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

then get back the values as an array

```
function getCheckedValues(valeur) {
  Browser.msgBox(valeur)
  // do something
}
```